# What instruction modifies the status flags in the CPSR register?

Tags: arm

For example, does 'ADD r1,r1,r2' modify the status flags in the CPSR? If it doesn't, Why? I thought it would update Carry flag if overflows.

Comment: please continue reading the instruction description, it tells you which flags are touched and if/when.

Comment: If you dont have the arm documentation then go to arms website and get it, which document depends on which architecture you are using.  based on your question I assume not a cortex-m so perhaps just get the armv5 architectural reference manual and start there.

Answer (score 0):

For most arithmetic and logic instructions, you have to add an 'S' at the end to update the condition flags. In your case :

```
ADDS r1, r1, r2
```

See this useful quick reference card about the ARM/Thumb-2 instruction set : http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001l/QRC0001_UAL.pdf